# Making a fictional game time / clock

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a game clock where each game hour are 3 real-time minutes. But I have a hard time wrapping my head around it for some reason.
I've came up with this half working bit, with a loop of 3 minutes for each hour so it's only showing full 'game hours' which I reset once above 23 to start a fresh day.
I guess I would have to update the loop to the accuracy of the game time clock?

```js
var hours;

if (process.argv.length > 2) {
  // setting the clock
  hours = parseInt(process.argv.slice(2));
}

console.log(hours);

let timerId = setInterval(function() {
  hours = hours + 1
  if (hours > 23) {
    hours = 0;
  }
  console.log(hours);
}, 3 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want it to show time more precisely than the hour?

Comment: You should save the start time. Then divide the time since starting by the ratio of real time to game time, e.g. 3600/180.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I'm trying to do. Sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to have a much faster repeating interval, at the level of game-seconds. If one game-hour is 3 real minutes, then game time actually runs 20 times as fast as real time, and so one game-second would last 1/20 real seconds, i.e. 50 milliseconds.

```js
const speed = 20; // how many times faster than real time
let clockDiv = document.querySelector("#clock");
let gameStartTime = 0; // game-milliseconds;
let realStartTime = Date.now(); // real milliseconds

let timerId = setInterval(function() {
  let gameTime = gameStartTime + (Date.now() - realStartTime) * speed;
  let sec = Math.floor(gameTime / 1000) % 60;
  let min = Math.floor(gameTime / 60000) % 60;
  let hour = Math.floor(gameTime / 3600000) % 24;
  // output in hh:mm:ss format:
  clockDiv.textContent = `${hour}:${min}:${sec}`.replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&");
}, 50);
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. Although I wonder if updating each 50ms could be too harsh on the computing? Or don't I have to worry about that?

Comment: No worries about that. If you have intensive computing in other parts of your code, those will just run to completion before the event queue is consumed again.

Comment: @F.Rakes The code above recomputes the game time from scratch on every tick, so can 1. set the interval longer if you feel like it’s slowing things down (although computers can do a *LOT* more at a 20fps rate); 2. even if the handler is delayed, the code is correct (in fact you shouldn’t rely on timers firing exactly or even close to the chosen interval, particularly in JS.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm entirely sure where your problem is, but @ 3 mins real time = 1 hour game time, 1 real second = 20 game seconds. 3600 / 180 = 20. You should be able to feed the game seconds into any normal time function to get minutes/hours etc.